# Modifying the value of an attribute in shapefile spacial object read with readOGR()

Tags: r, maps, shapefile, rgdal

I am using a shapfile that defines the map of Portugal that has two errors and I am struggling to correct them.

The files are available in the following page [shapefile] (https://dados.gov.pt/pt/datasets/concelhos-de-portugal/).

I am reading the file with the `readOGR()` method from the rgdal package and I am not able to modify the `$NAME_2` variable.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
library( rgdal )
shapefile <- readOGR( dsn="./shapefiles/concelhos-shapefile" , layer = "concelhos" , use_iconv = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") 


shapefile [  shapefile$CCA_2== '0308' ,  ]@data$NAME_2 <- "Guimarães"

shapefile [  shapefile$CCA_2== '0814' ,  ]@data$NAME_2 <- "Tavira"
```

With this I get the error:

> Error in as.vector(data) :
> no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector "

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Solved. 
I was not accessing the dataframe in the right way. The following instruction works:

shapefile@data[shapefile@data$CCA_2 == '0308', ]$NAME_2 <- "Guimarães"

Comment: Can you post it as an answer for future reference?